# RCP Tycho override manifest with pom version

Tags: java, maven, rcp, tycho

I want to override Manifest version witch maven version, it is possible ? I know that that I can override pom version with manifest with update-pom, but how about something opposite ?

Comment: No, this is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Well, this is not necessarily the end of the story. Tycho is an open source project, so you can always request features that don't exist yet. So if you have a good use case for this feature, let the project know by [opening an issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho) of severity 'enhancement'.

Comment: Thx. My use case is: I have some plugins grouped in feature and they have same versions and they have one parent. I wanted to manage versions only at this one parent pom.